Upon IOS app transfer or migration, what are the effects if user did not upgrade app from app-store
We are ready to migrate the app from  Developer-Account A to Developer-Account B, and we are wondering what the impact is on users who originally installed the app when the app still belonged to developer account A.
Can you explain any side affects?
For example: user Sign-In with Apple Id, does the value of ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential.user returned by AuthenticationServices change? Is this .user value  related to Developer-Account A or Developer-Account B?
func sendRequest() {
        let provider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
        let request = provider.createRequest()
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName]
        let authorization = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        authorization.delegate = self
        authorization.performRequests()
    }
    
    //AuthenticationServices delegate call back
    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, 
                                 didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
        //Did get user identifier
        let credential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential
        let user = credential?.user
        // did this user value changed after App migration, When users use older versions
    }

